# Select statement formatting

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to match up data from two tables. One is an invoices table with the date when a thing goes out and when it comes back in. The other is a line item table with each item on an invoice. Both tables have the column invoice_number in common.

The SELECT statement I made is:

```sql
SELECT line_items.invoice_number,date_out,date_due_in,equipment_qty,line_items.equipment_id FROM invoices join line_items
group by sequence;
```

example of some of the output is:

```
invoice_number, date_out, date_due_in, equipment_qty, equipment_id
1   2017-01-06  2017-01-13  3   2
1   2017-01-06  2017-01-13  2   3
2   2017-01-06  2017-01-13  5   2
3   2017-01-06  2017-01-13  1   2
3   2017-01-06  2017-01-13  1   5
```

The issue is that it's putting the date of the first item on all of the items.

Here is an example of the tables it's pulling from:

Invoices:

```
invoice_number, invoice_date, customer_id,  equipment_total, date_out, date_due_in
1   2017-01-06  1   5   2017-01-06  2017-01-13
2   2017-01-08  2   4   2017-01-17  2017-01-19
3   2017-01-16  2   2   2017-01-16  2017-01-18
```

Line items:

```
Sequence, invoice_number, equipment_id, equipment_qty
1   1   2   3
2   1   3   2
3   2   2   5
4   3   2   1
```

What am I missing from the SELECT statement?

Comment: `.. join line_items using (invoice_number)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `JOIN`, always use the `ON` or `USING (fields, ...)` part of the [syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

In this case the field name in both tables was the same, `invoice_number`, so `USING (invoice_number)` was an appropriate syntax.

If they where different names `ON invoices.ID = line_item.invoice_number` syntax could be used.

Multiple conditions could be used so the criteria can be used in some ways like the the `WHERE` criteria of SQL.